# Node-Red I can't install nodes

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red

I have something wrong with Node-red. After installing library nothing appears in Node-red. I was trying to find this issue on the internet for several hours but nothing help.

I guess problem is with directory...

Could you help me please?

Thanks

**Here you can see install log of NPMJS and Library:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5450  100  5450    0     0  22708      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22803
tar=/bin/tar
version:
tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright © 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Napsali John Gilmore a Jay Fenlason.
install npm@latest
fetching: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-6.14.6.tgz
up to date in 0.334s
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/bin/npx -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.14.6
added 435 packages from 877 contributors in 54.249s
It worked
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm install node-red-contrib-opcua
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-opcua
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
npm WARN pi No description
npm WARN pi No repository field.
npm WARN pi No README data
npm WARN pi No license field.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-opcua
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-opcua'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-opcua']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-opcua\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/pi/node_modules/node-red-contrib-opcua' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-07-09T09_31_09_039Z-debug.log
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo npm install node-red-contrib-opcua
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
npm WARN pi No description
npm WARN pi No repository field.
npm WARN pi No README data
npm WARN pi No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})

+ node-red-contrib-opcua@0.2.66
updated 1 package and audited 649 packages in 24.45s

24 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 89 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

**Log of reccomeded commands:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm fund
/home/pi
├─┬ https://opencollective.com/node-red-contrib-modbus
│ └── node-red-contrib-modbus@5.13.3
├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/sindresorhus
│ └── mimic-response@2.1.0, p-limit@2.3.0
├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/feross
│ └── safe-buffer@5.2.1
├─┬ https://www.patreon.com/feross
│ └── safe-buffer@5.2.1
├─┬ https://feross.org/support
│ └── safe-buffer@5.2.1
├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/erossignon
│ └── node-opcua@2.7.0
├─┬ https://github.com/chalk/chalk?sponsor=1
│ └── chalk@4.1.0
├─┬ https://github.com/chalk/ansi-styles?sponsor=1
│ └── ansi-styles@4.2.1
├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
│ └── rimraf@3.0.2, glob@7.1.6
├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/jonschlinkert
│ └── picomatch@2.2.2
├─┬ https://opencollective.com/core-js
│ └── core-js-pure@3.6.5
└─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb
  └── deep-equal@1.1.1, is-date-object@1.0.2, is-regex@1.1.0, object-is@1.1.2, regexp.prototype.flags@1.3.0, has-symbols@1.0.1, es-abstract@1.17.6, es-to-primitive@1.2.1, is-callable@1.2.0, object-inspect@1.8.0, string.prototype.trimend@1.0.1, string.prototype.trimstart@1.0.1, is-symbol@1.0.3
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-07-09T09_56_29_012Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Trying changing file/directory permission and then retry npm install.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to install nodes in the wrong directory. To install Node-RED nodes you need to be in the userDIR (this is logged at startup, but is normally `/home/pi/.node-red` on a Raspberry Pi)

Second the permission error implies that you have tried to run `npm` as root at some point. You should not be using sudo to run npm normally.